# json parse string

Tags: objective-c, json

i create php server and i call  this function  in my objective c

```
public function getCOMPAINs (){

      $query = "SELECT COMPAINCOMPAIN_ID FROM COMPAIN_USER WHERE USERUSER_ID = '$this->USER_ID'";
            $MyConnection = new MyConnection();
      $result = mysql_query($query,$MyConnection->Connection) or die(mysql_error());
    while($obj=mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
        $res[] = array( 'COMPAIN_ID' => $obj->COMPAINCOMPAIN_ID);
    }
    return json_encode( $res);



  }
```

if i try call this function with php i can show this response

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["COMPAIN_ID"]=>
    string(2) "44"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["COMPAIN_ID"]=>
    string(2) "46"
  }
}
```

How can I parse this response data with Json?i try to do this solution but this using with xml

```
 - (NSMutableData *)sendRequestCompains{

        NSMutableString *sRequest = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        [sRequest appendString:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"];
        [sRequest appendString:@"<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"];
        [sRequest appendString:@"<soap:Body>"];
        [sRequest appendString:@"<getCOMPAINs xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/PlatformService/method\">"];
        [sRequest appendString:@"<Id_USR>"];    // any attribute
        [sRequest appendString:@"1"];    // attribute value
        [sRequest appendString:@"</Id_USR>"];
        [sRequest appendString:@"</getCOMPAINs>"];
        [sRequest appendString:@"</soap:Body>"];
        [sRequest appendString:@"</soap:Envelope>"];


        NSURL   *ServiceURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://79.249.37.1/server_comp.php"];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:ServiceURL];
        [request addValue:@"text/xml; charset:UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request addValue:@"http://79.249.37.1/server_comp.php/getCOMPAINs" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"]; 
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setHTTPBody:[sRequest dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        if (conn) {
            data = [[NSData data] retain];
            NSLog(@"Connection success");
            [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
            NSError *WSerror;
            NSURLResponse *WSresponse;

        data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&WSresponse error:&WSerror];
            NSLog(@"slt%d",[data length]);
        }






        return data;
    }
```

i try this solution but not work

```
NSData * webData=[[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:self.sendRequestCompains];



    // Create new SBJSON parser object
    SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];



    NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:webData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSArray *statuses = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];

    for (NSDictionary *status in statuses)
    {

        NSLog(@"%@", [status objectForKey:@"0"]);
    }


    the response recived from server
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:getCOMPAINsResponse xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/PlatformService/method"><COMPAIN xsi:type="xsd:string">[{&quot;COMPAIN_ID&quot;:&quot;44&quot;},{&quot;COMPAIN_ID&quot;:&quot;46&quot;}]</COMPAIN></ns1:getCOMPAINsResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

i try this solution but not work

> ```
> NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL
> ```
>
> URLWithString:@"http://79.249.37.1/server_comp.php/getCOMPAINs.json?userId=1"]];
>
> ```
>   // execution de la requête et récupération du JSON via un objet
> ```
>
> NSData
>         NSData *response = [NSURLConnection
>   sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
>
> ```
>   // On récupère le JSON en NSString depuis la réponse
>   NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response
> ```
>
> encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
>
> ```
>   // on parse la reponse JSON
>   NSArray *statuses = [parser objectWithString:json_string
> ```
>
> error:nil];
>
> ```
>   for (NSDictionary *status in statuses)
>   {
>       // on peut recuperer les valeurs en utilisant objectForKey à
> ```
>
> partir du status qui est un NSDictionary
>             // on log le tweet et le nom de l utilisateur
>             NSLog(@"%@", [status objectForKey:@"COMPAIN_ID"]);
>         }

Comment: Add the response from your server (The JSON, not the PHP pritn_r output!) to the question please! One of your comments below says 'recive json in xml string' and that makes no sense at all - we need more information.

Comment: this the json includ in response
[{&quot;COMPAIN_ID&quot;:&quot;44&quot;},{&quot;COMPAIN_ID&quot;:&quot;46&quot;}]

Comment: There's no XML there at all, why are you talking about 'xml string' ?

Comment: becuase the response recived  start with <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-

Comment: so the code you posted in your previous comment wasn't the complete response! Why can't you parse the XML to get the JSON and then just parse the JSON?

Comment: but i want use json to have easy parse

Comment: If you want to use _only_ JSON thne you need to tell your server not to wrap in XML. While it's in the XML, you can't just use JSON and expect it to work.

Comment: haw i tell my server that i will work with json

Comment: I have no idea - I don't know what server you're running etc!

Comment: i no have problem about the response from my server ,my problem is in my function  sendRequestCompains because i write [request addValue:@"text/xml; ....

Answer (score 3):

You want to use JSON to parse the response but the response is wrapped in some XML.

You have two options :

1) Parse the XML to get the JSON and then parse that as JSON

2) Ask the server not to wrap your response in the XML, just return the JSON.

You seem to be talking to the server with SOAP (from sendRequestCompains) - there's not much chance that if you make a SOAP request it will return a JSON object! I think your best bet would be option (1).

However, if you have control over your server I would stop using SOAP at all and get it to response to something like

```
http://79.249.37.1/server_comp.php/getCOMPAINs.json?Id_USR=1
```

I'm passing the paramters just as URL params, not as a SOAP object. I'm also specifying that I'm interested in a json response with the *.json* at the end of the URL.

Comment: haw i can ask my  server  to not  wrap  response in the XML and use  just return the JSON

Comment: haw i can get my Id_USR=1 in my function  getCOMPAINs?

Comment: getCOMPAINs is my function in sever and what u mean  getCOMPAINs.json?

Comment: I'ld stick to option 1. You're already almost there, you just need to strip the additional XML from your input and then decode the html-entities from your JSON.

Comment: @Tim van Elsloo - I'm for option (1) as well - parsing that XML should be pretty simple; it would have taken less time just to parse it than it would to have all the arguments he's had on this question ;)

Answer (score 1):

See this question: [Native JSON support in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562478/native-json-support-in-ios) , which refers to this link: http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/

Comment: the problem that i recive json in xml string

Comment: i not use json file but i recive string from my server

Comment: can i change sendRequestCompains to use json?

Comment: The response looks like SOAP to me. http://sudzc.com/ does a great job in generating an iPhone project, that parses SOAP responses. From there on, you can use a JSON parser. Or take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966401/wcf-using-the-same-code-for-soap-and-json-implementation

Comment: if i not want use soap her and just use json can i do this?

Comment: look this please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876529/wcf-use-json-to-encode-a-soap-message-body

Comment: To get your ID's in php, you can use this:
echo $res[0]["COMPAIN_ID"]    // If that's not it, try to explain more detailed your problem, because I'm getting lost in all the comments/questions. I'm sure if you structure your question, someone will answer it soon!

Comment: haw i can recive  json forma and not xml forma from my server

Answer (score 0):

Before this line:

```
NSArray *statuses = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];
```

Add these lines:

```
json_string = [json_string stringByReplacingOccurancesOfString:@"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:getCOMPAINsResponse xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/PlatformService/method"><COMPAIN xsi:type="xsd:string">" withString:@""];
json_string = [json_string stringByReplacingOccurancesOfString:@"</COMPAIN></ns1:getCOMPAINsResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>" withString:@""];
```

This is hardcoded, so you need to be sure this won't change.

What's left is the `json_string`, but encoded with html-entities. To decode it, add this class to your project:
https://discussions.apple.com/message/8064367#8064367

And add another line before `NSArray *statuses ...`.

```
json_string = [[[MREntitiesConverter alloc] init] convertEntiesInString:json_string];
```