# How to browse NSDictionary?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I've written the following code which should browse an NSDictionary :

```
json_string=@"[{\"COMPAIN\":\"44\"},{\"COMPAIN\",\"46\"}]";
     NSArray *statuses = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];
     for (NSDictionary *status in statuses)
     {                  
          NSLog(@"%@", [status objectForKey:@"COMPAIN"]);
     }
```

However, this code isnt browsing correctly.

How can I fix the above code in order to browse an NSDictionary?

Answer (score 2):

It's because your `*status` isn't a `NSDictionary` and your `*statuses` isn't an `NSArray`.

Your json-string is an associative array. However, it contains the same key 2 times.

Try replacing your JSON-string (so edit your back-end) so it becomes:

```
[{"COMPAIN":"44"}, {"COMPAIN", "46"}]
```

If you use PHP, just use `json_encode` and PHP will generate a json-string out of it =)!

---

```
// json_string now is [{"COMPAIN":"44"}, {"COMPAIN", "46"}]; so ...
NSArray *statuses = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];
for (NSDictionary *status in statuses)
{                  
     NSLog(@"%@", [status objectForKey:@"COMPAIN"]);
}
```

This is the same code as you already was using, so it should work now =)!

Comment: i change but i have 2011-07-28 08:23:34.542 IAA2[14388:207] COMPAIN

Comment: What is your console telling you after doing `NSLog(json_string);`?

Comment: the problem that i return json_encode(value) from my server  but i recived  this json in xml  haw i do to ?

Comment: look my problem please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842864/json-parse-string

Comment: my bro Tim van Elsloo u see my problem?

Comment: I'm sorry, but you'll have to solve that problem first. Before solving this problem, you need to be sure the JSON outputted by your server is correct (and right now, it isn't). I'll take a loop at your other question =)!

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:getCOMPAINsResponse xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/PlatformService/method"><COMP xsi:type="xsd:string">[{&quot;COMPAIN&quot;:&quot;44&quot;},{&quot;COMPAIN&quot;:&quot;46&quot;}]</COMP></ns1:getCOMPAINsResponse></SOAP-ENV>

Comment: this is what i recive in my iphone

Comment: Okay, now you could hardcode things a bit. I'll post my solution in your other topic (the link you just gave me).

Comment: [{"COMPAIN":"44"}, {"COMPAIN", "46"}] ok i have this string haw i can parse?

Comment: I'm glad I could help you in your previous topic. I'll edit my answer here so it fits =)!

Comment: json_string=@"[{\"COMPAIN_ID\":\"44\",\"COMPAIN_ID\":\"46\"}]";
 NSArray *statuses = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];
 for (NSDictionary *status in statuses)
 {                  
  NSLog(@"%@", [status objectForKey:@"COMPAIN_ID"]);
 }